# Why dried, closed coconuts go through carbonation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, food-chemistry

Some dried, closed coconuts go through carbonation:

- The white meat of the coconut becomes disintegrated and smeary
- The liquid becomes carbonated with a bit sour-salty tasted coconut water (which reminds the taste of a water and baking soda solution) and a grey to blue color
- If the grey-blue liquid given enough time (inside a dried, closed coconut) it could become yellowish and possibly contaminated (I have no idea if the yellow color is due to further carbonation or bacteria)

Given that a dried, closed coconut is a dry and sealed by hard, fibrous shell,
Why dried, closed coconuts go through carbonation?

Comment: Hello to mods; if you think this is a better fit for biology SE, please don't hesitate to migrate. I assumed here it will be better due to biochemical process.

Comment: I can recall the bad taste of very old coconut water. It does get fermented. Sugars are converted to carbon dioxide and sugars to organic acid.

Comment: Hint 1: what causes champagne to become carbonated? Hint 2: What is the etymology of the English word *enzyme*?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Are you 100% sure that yeast causes carbonation of coconut meat and liquid? When I search yeast and coconut, all I find is articles saying that coconut oil can be used as a remedy for yeast infections. There seems to be evidence for destroying yeast, but no evidence for containing yeast. Do you have a source?

Comment: @user1271772  actually yeast can ferment coconut oil see the link in my comment

Comment: @JohnDoea see this link : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0740002086900092

Comment: why does it say modified by organicgem and i dont see any modifications?